# Regular expressions in SQLalchemy queries?

Tags: python, regex, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to use a regex in a way similar to `session.query(MyObject).filter_by(REGEX)`?

If not, how can I use sqlAlchemy to retrieve records that have a varchar PK beginning with a certain value (e.g. all those whose *city* field begins with "SA")? Thanks.

Comment: If using Oracle, you'll want to use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14750641/269834

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.op('regexp')(REGEX))
```

Comment: This answer will only work in MySQL, which uses `REGEXP` as a comparison operator. You'll have to change it in other databases, and it will only work like this if the database has a regular expression comparison operator (as opposed to, for example, a function). In PostgreSQL, you can use `op('~')`.

Comment: Also seems to work with SQLite3.

Comment: When I use this with SQLite3 I get `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: regexp`

Answer (score 11):

For the record, you can do essentially the same syntax as Paulo Scardine's answer in SQLAlchemy too;

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.like('something%'))
```

Comment: Why the downvote? *Literally* all I'm doing is providing a SQLAlchemy translation to describe another answer. I'm not claiming it's better, or even that the answer I'm translating is the best solution. If there's something wrong comment and correct (and there may well be), but don't arbitrarily donwvote!

Comment: This is a 'like', not a 'regex' as asked for in the question.

Comment: Even though this isn't using a regex (as asked per OP) it's offering a solution to the actual problem. OP doesn't *need* to use a regex for the given problem, so this is still helpful for their specific question,.

Comment: @kevlarr Their specific question is about RegularExpressions. When other people search the site, that's what they expect. Their specific _example_ could be solved by other methods, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @KerryJones The OP asked about regex *but also specified* "If not, how can I...". OP wanted to solve a problem, regex was the way they thought to, they asked for alternatives, and this answer provides a **very reasonable one** that fit within the ORM they are asking about. This type of answer is explicitly encouraged by [StackOverflow's own guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers. The title doesn't accurately reflect their question, and focusing on regex here is a perfect example of **the XY problem**.

Comment: @kevlarr fair point about what they ask for (I'm not one of the downvoters), though I might not totally agree with SO's questions and I find that most voters on the website tend to vote down an answer that is not what's being asked for

Comment: @KerryJones So regardless of SO's guidelines, users really dictate what's (not) acceptable.. Good point.

Comment: That's literally true, due to downvoting.

Comment: Yep.. It's just unfortunate that SO users down-vote the way they do. Neither Alex's or Paulo's even *should have* been, because it wasn't a "regex-only" question in the first place. Users need to read more than just the title.

Answer (score 11):

as of SqlAlchemy 1.4, there's a built-in regular expression operator, [regexp_match](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.regexp_match).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 2):

[DISCLAIMER: no regex]

I'm answering to the question "how can I use sqlAlchemy to retrieve records that have a varchar PK beginning with a certain value" because for this simple use case a `LIKE` probably is both less expensive and more portable (asking for regular expressions seems like a manifestation of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

In SQLAlquemy (borrowing from Alex):

```
session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.like('something%'))
```

In SqlSoup I use:

```
db.table.filter(db.table.column.like('something%'))
```

Comment: Why the downvote? A regex is clearly overkill to test for a string begining with "something". Also, not every database has native regex support but every SQL database supports "like" statements - server side operations are always better.

Comment: @Sylvestre ...and way more expensive and less portable.

Comment: @UloPe Asking for regex for that use case is a manifestation of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also, the question does not state something like "please, only regex answers". The real question and the one answered here is "how can I use sqlAlchemy to retrieve records that have a varchar PK beginning with a certain value".

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are also trying to use regex in MSSQL Databases:

You can bring regex support by [writing OLE Functions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/#third)

but maybe you are not comfortable with the idea of writing functional extensions to your MSSQL Database or you simply are not allowed to do this.

Unfortunately, the use of [regexp_match](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.regexp_match) as mentioned by [Todd Jacobus Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69003021/15484549) in sqlalchemy 1.4 (latest release) is not [backend-agnostic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.regexp_match) which includes MSSQL Databases.

However you might be able to "translate" your regex into a [wildcard-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals) that you can use with the "LIKE" operator.

Unlike MySQL, MSSQL (or T-SQL) is capable of using wildcards
EG: '[A-Z0-9]%' matching a string of any length that must start with any letter from A to Z or numeral from 0 to 9. 
[Here you can see some useful examples](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html)

By fully translating a regex into a wildcard expression, the resulting expression however might not be very convenient to the reader. 
EG: '[A-Z0-9]{5}' will translate into '[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]' since quantors are only poorly available (_ and %).

When you are looking for a backend-agnostic, "good enough" solution, you may help yourself by using the "LIKE" operator with an expression that comes close to your regex to narrow down the number of results, and then filter the results again in your program logic.