# sqlalchemy using custom methods in filter

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm having a problem with this sqlalchemy query:

```
def bvalue(value):
    if isinstance(value, unicode):
        value = re.sub('[^\w]', "", value).lower()
    return value

basicValue = bvalue(someVariable)

q = self.session.query(sheet.id).\
    filter(bvalue(sheet.column) == basicValue)
```

The bvalue function works. I'm trying to match values after stripping them from any special characters and capitalisation. The stripped variable does match with the stripped db value, but still the query is not retrieving any results.

What am I doing wrong? Can't you use custom methods in filters?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that SQLAlchemy translates your queries into plain SQL statements that are then emitted to your configured database?

So naturally you can't simply add arbitrary python functions, since they would have to be translated into SQL which can't be done in a generic way.

Aside from this general issue,  `bvalue(sheet.column)` will simply return `sheet.column` (since it's not a unicode instance) and it is evaluated before creating the query. So your query is in fact equivalent to:

```
q = self.session.query(sheet.id).\
    filter(sheet.column == basicValue)
```

How to get the regex into SQL depends on the database you're using. Check e.g.
[REGEXP_LIKE in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750382/regexp-like-in-sqlalchemy/14750641#14750641)
for a some suggestions.