# Instantiation model class object from pure SQL query?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on my first proper web-app, following the 'Flask Mega-Tutorial'. It's helped me get started with SQLAlchemy ORM and given me some understanding of how to use this tool.

For instance, I have a class Pet. I can call

```
foo = Pet.query.filter_where(id=1).first()
```

this results in foo of class Pet. The definition of Pet has many attributes, but each is of they type 'db.Column', which makes sense because each Pet is a record in the Pets table.

Where I'm confused is now I want to execute more sophisticate SQL against the Pet table but still have access to those records as Pet objects.

```
pets = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM pet WHERE blahblah = blahblah').fetch_all()
```

And now I have this pets List which all of the attributes for each Pet record returned by the query.

How do I now instantiate objects of class Pet for each of these records? When I query with the ORM, I get objects back. My Pet class as defined in app/models.py does not have an **init** that accepts any arguments.

Right now I am taking the list of results, grabbing the "id" value from the results, and then in a for loop creating all of them as objects

```
pets = db.session.execute('SELECT * FROM pet WHERE blahblah = blahblah').fetch_all()

pet_objects=[]

for p in pets:
  record_id = p.id
  pet_object = Pet.query.filter_where(id=record_id)
  pet_objects.append(pet_object)
```

From which point I can treat my list of Pet objects as I would the results of a query using the ORM which would return objects automatically.

My question is, am I doing this correctly? Seems incorrect because for each record I hit the db initially with my SQL and then again to instantiate the object by its 'id' but I am not sure of how else to go from record -> Object in this framework.

Sorry for the long question, but I've been grappling with this for a while.

Comment: This may be useful... https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to achieve the result of this query `SELECT * FROM pet WHERE blahblah = blahblah` using `sqlalchemy`.

You can use `filter_by` method in the `base query` class:

for example for your query you can use this:

`pet_objects =  Pet.query.filter_by(blahblah='blahblah').all()`

You can create even more sophisticated queries using a join or  simply add more where constraints with adding more arguments to `filter_by` for example:
`query.filter_by(col_1= 'something', col_2 = 'another thing')`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I do think that you're right but I ran into some snags with ORM filtering options when my queries got to a certain level of complexity -- right now I need regex/wildcard text searches, and OR clauses to find the right records.

I'm going to take a look at the tutorial someone posted as a comment above and see if it helps out.

Comment: your welcome, you can find useful thing for regex queries in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4112402/2754195
if you explain more, I'll will help you in your case.
but i think something like `session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.like('something%'))` will help you in many cases(and its cheaper than regex)!