# Flask-SqlAlchemy filter full word matching

Tags: python, mysql, regex, flask, sqlalchemy

I've hit a brick wall when it comes to attempting to do full word matching during a flask-sqlalchemy filter query.

Currently in my code, i'm using ilike and %+search_term+% to find items within my database, but whenever I use a term like "king" it will obviously match to thing such as 'unlocking' or 'tracking'.  I would only like to match 'king' by itself, regardless of location in the string, but not when it is part of another word.

```
regex_var = r'\bking\b'
test_var = re.search(regex_var,'this is unlocking a king')
print(test_var)
test = database.query.filter(database.title.op('regex')(regex_var)).all()
```

In my above example, the regex test works totally fine and will only match the last 'king' in the test string and will fail if I remove the 'king' from the end of the test string.  But whenever I try it with the database query, regardless of how I format the regex queries, be it with 'regexp_match' or 'op', it won't find anything or will throw errors.  I've also tried '\\bking\\b' which fails the first test as well as the second test.  I've tried removing the raw string 'r', which obviously did not help, and only having the term 'king' in there performs the same as the ilike %...% query returning results where 'king' is still a substring of 'unlocking' etc.  If I remove the 'all()' at the end, it won't throw any errors, but the final query isn't iterable at all, and will throw errors the second I try to iterate or manipulate any of the contents.

Through all of my test.. the special characters like ^ or $ work fine within the regex expression, but the special sequence like '\b' will not work.**

I've tried researching wildcard flags that might be more effective for ilike % that would be more effective for the beginning and end string matching like '\b' for regex but haven't found anything thus far.

Looking for help or advice from anyone else that has come across a similar issue.  I've pretty much already tried everything that I've found within all relevant posts in on this site, thus I am posting my question now because none of them have worked so far.

Comment: Can you add which db you are using ? Also please keep your question short, explain it with concrete and concise examples, avoid cluttering the question with extra wordings.

Comment: @BcK sorry for the length, I've just seen many responses that request that we explain everything that we have tried.  I'm using MySQL.  I also just tried using a direct SqlAlchemy select statement that is yielding the same issue of not reading the '\b'

Comment: If you are using old versions of MySQL, you need not `\b` but `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, i.e. `r'[[:<:]]king[[:>:]]'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Admittingly, my Mysql version is 5.7 and I'm upgrading it right now, but regarding your solution, it didn't work unfortunately.  I really wish it did.  I'm getting the same syntax errors as I did when using \b.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expressions in SQLalchemy queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112337/regular-expressions-in-sqlalchemy-queries)

Comment: @YaakovBressler that was the first post that I came across, hence why I even considered using regex for doing the query, and no, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
FULLTEXT(col)

MATCH(col) AGAINST("king" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Will match *words* "king", "kings" and maybe a few others, but not "working".

Either king or queen (anywhere in `col`):

```
MATCH(col) AGAINST("king queen" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Both king and queen:

```
MATCH(col) AGAINST("+king +queen" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Old Regexp (for "or"):

```
col REGEXP "[[:<:]](king|queen)[[:>:]]"
```

New Regexp (for "or"):

```
col REGEXP "\\b(king|queen)\\b"
```

FULLTEXT indexing has some limitations.  But when it is applicable it is much faster than `LIKE` or `REGEXP` (aka `RLIKE`).