# How to retrieve text by a keyword which contains punctuation?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLite with SQLAlchemy as ORM. I want to retrieve sentences with some keywords.

I consider situations in which a keyword appears at the start/end of the sentence using `table.message.startswith(keyword)` and `table.message.endswith(keyword)` (or`table.message.ilike(f' {keyword} ')`). But when the keyword starts or ends with punctuation:

```bash
"This is first example. This will continue..."
```

I can't retrieve anything using `example` or `continue` as keyword. I tried `table.message.ilike(f'%{keyword}%')` but retrieved sentences which do not contain the keyword.

Comment: Check out [Regular expressions in SQLalchemy queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112337/regular-expressions-in-sqlalchemy-queries)

Comment: Yes. but got this error `sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
`

Comment: I used `re.compile(r'keyword')` as regex pattern

Comment: Check out : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.regexp_match

Comment: If it contains punctuation, you should use `re.compile(re.escape(r'keyword']))` to treat them literally.

Comment: @Barmar i got erorr using re.compile. tried to use raw regex string `r'regexPattern'` and it works but actually dont know a regex pattern to match sentences when a keywords ends with punctuations.

Comment: regexp makes query slow. I have about 100 milion rows @JonSG

Comment: Are you now looking for a pattern like `\bexample\b` or do you have that and it is is just too slow?

Comment: That's why you need to use `re.escape()`.

Comment: @JonSG `\bexample\b` match exact keyword  like `example` not keywords like `example\\n`.

Comment: @Barmar I used re.escape() as REGEX pattern inside `session.query(Object).filter(Object.column.op('regexp')(REGEX))` but not worked (mean did not retrieve anything)

Comment: I'm a little surprised by that not matching. It seems to work here https://regex101.com/r/0aqFPS/1

Comment: In this link there is `gm` after `"`. How can i use in as regex pattern in sqlalchemy @JonSG

Comment: when i dont use `gm`, it fail for multi keywords. https://regex101.com/r/WCjEOU/1 @JonSG

Comment: Can you include results that are incorrectly matching ? Seems that `ilike` seems to work fine with your example.

Comment: The flags are passed as a parameter something like `re.Multiline` but I am no longer at my computer to test it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how slow this would really be but I think it can be improved.

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func, or_
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)


class Result(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'results'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String)



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


should_match = ["This is first example. This will continue...", "Let us continue the example", "Continue reading example!!"]
should_not_match = ["To be continued but not matched", "Not a match", "Not matching again...."]


def check_matches(matches):
    lower_matches = [m.lower() for m in matches]
    lower_matches.sort()
    lower_should_match = [item.lower() for item in should_match]
    lower_should_match.sort()
    assert lower_matches == lower_should_match, str(lower_matches) + "==" + str(lower_should_match)

with Session(engine) as session:
    for text in should_match:
        session.add(Result(text=text))
    for text in should_not_match:
        session.add(Result(text=text))
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    keywords = ["continue", "example"]
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        and_args.append(Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%'))
    # Subquery select to try to whittle large result set down before expensive replace/ilike operations.
    stmt = select(Result.text).where(*and_args).subquery()
    to_replace = [".", ",", "?", ",", "!"]
    cond = stmt.c.text
    for sub in to_replace:
        cond = func.replace(cond, sub, " ")
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        start_cond = cond.ilike(keyword+" %")
        middle_cond = cond.ilike("% "+keyword+" %")
        end_cond = cond.ilike("% "+keyword)
        and_args.append(or_(start_cond, middle_cond, end_cond))
    stmt2 = select(stmt.c.text).where(*and_args)
    matches = [r for r in session.execute(stmt2).scalars()]
    check_matches(matches)


with Session(engine) as session:
    keywords = ["continue", "example"]
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        and_args.append(Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%'))
    # Subquery select to try to whittle large result set down before expensive regexp operations.
    stmt = select(func.lower(Result.text).label('text2')).where(*and_args).subquery()
    and_args = [stmt.c.text2.regexp_match(r"\b" + keyword + r"\b") for keyword in keywords]
    stmt2 = select(stmt.c.text2).where(*and_args)
    matches = [r for r in session.execute(stmt2).scalars()]
    check_matches(matches)
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func, or_
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


Base = declarative_base()


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)


class Result(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'results'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    text = Column(String)



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


should_match = ["This is first example. This will continue...", "Let us continue the example", "Continue reading example!!"]
should_not_match = ["To be continued but not matched", "Not a match", "Not matching again...."]


def check_matches(matches):
    lower_matches = [m.lower() for m in matches]
    lower_matches.sort()
    lower_should_match = [item.lower() for item in should_match]
    lower_should_match.sort()
    assert lower_matches == lower_should_match, str(lower_matches) + "==" + str(lower_should_match)

with Session(engine) as session:
    for text in should_match:
        session.add(Result(text=text))
    for text in should_not_match:
        session.add(Result(text=text))
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    keywords = ["continue", "example"]
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        and_args.append(Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%'))
    # Subquery select to try to whittle large result set down before expensive replace/ilike operations.
    stmt = select(Result.text).where(*and_args).subquery()
    to_replace = [".", ",", "?", ",", "!"]
    cond = stmt.c.text
    for sub in to_replace:
        cond = func.replace(cond, sub, " ")
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        start_cond = cond.ilike(keyword+" %")
        middle_cond = cond.ilike("% "+keyword+" %")
        end_cond = cond.ilike("% "+keyword)
        and_args.append(or_(start_cond, middle_cond, end_cond))
    stmt2 = select(stmt.c.text).where(*and_args)
    matches = [r for r in session.execute(stmt2).scalars()]
    check_matches(matches)


with Session(engine) as session:
    keywords = ["continue", "example"]
    and_args = []
    for keyword in keywords:
        and_args.append(Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%'))
    # Subquery select to try to whittle large result set down before expensive regexp operations.
    stmt = select(func.lower(Result.text).label('text2')).where(*and_args).subquery()
    and_args = [stmt.c.text2.regexp_match(r"\b" + keyword + r"\b") for keyword in keywords]
    stmt2 = select(stmt.c.text2).where(*and_args)
    matches = [r for r in session.execute(stmt2).scalars()]
    check_matches(matches)
```

Comment: Thanks but, I wanna search with multiple keywords which all of them must exists in sentences. In other hand your example is exactly the problem which i mentioned before.
 `Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%')` retrieve sentences with keyword not exact keyword (except punctuation).
For example by this query `Result.text.ilike(f'%example%')` you may find sentence which contains `examples` token

Comment: I think I don't understand what you have written.  Can you explain it a different way or with a more complete example?  Does the keyword actually contain the punctuation ?

Comment: Check this link: https://regex101.com/r/WCjEOU/1
I have a text which must be retrieve with two keywords ['example', 'continue']. no matter using `regexp` or `ilike`query. Keywords does not contains punctuations but sentences in  the database are not normalized.

Comment: What i am doing now is, retrieving all the matched sentences with `Result.text.ilike(f'%{keyword}%')` then after normalizing, check if any of them contains exatly all of keywords. I want to do this in a single query.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be working but I think I understand your question after rereading a bunch.

Comment: Yeah it seems like it is going to be slow no matter what but maybe you could perform the first query and then select from that query to speed it up.

Comment: ofcourse processing after first query is more powerful but i am not sure if it is more performance efficient.

Comment: I think regexp is going to probably be faster and you could do the same trick and seems like it could be optimized a bit.  Also seems sort of language dependent based on what the punctuation is considered.

Comment: I added regexp example but seems like you would need to do a lot of testing to determine what speeds things up, maybe the subquery pre-filter helps and maybe not.

Comment: Thanks alot. using subquery was interesting to me.